# Paperclip: How to change "#" modifier behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I use Paperclip 2.3.11 in my Rails 3 application, and I create thumbnails using:

```
:styles => { :thumb => "80x80#" }
```

However, if the picture is small, say `32x32`, it is enlarged to fit thumbnail dimensions.

I would like to fix that by hacking Paperclip.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the relevant code that describes `#`'s behavior.

Could you please point me to the right place in Paperclip code ?

Or, maybe there is a better solution ? I would like the thumbnails to be `80x80` unless the original picture is too small (in which case the thumbnail should be the same size as the original picture).

Comment: use `:styles => { :thumb => "80x80" }`?

Comment: @NARKOZ: I mentioned explicitly that I want the thumbnails to be `80x80`. `:styles => { :thumb => "80x80" }` will result in `80x80` thumbnail only if the original image is square. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `#` is an argument used by Paperclip to know whether or not you expect the pic to be cropped.

It's written [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb), through the `crop?` method, itself looking at `geometry[-1,1]`: basically the last character of the style you enter.

You could then:

- try what's suggested by @David Sulc which seems ok regarding my previous explanation
- dig further in Paperclip's code and maybe rewrite `transformation_to` defined [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb)

Comment: The `#` modifier doesn't exist in ImageMagick. It's Paperclip's extension.

Comment: The first option doesn't work, so I guess I left with the second one :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `:styles => { :thumb => "80x80>#" }` ? (Sorry, can't try it out myself...)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The picture is still resized (like with `80x80#`).

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info of the Geometry String which is used by ImageMagick as in following:
http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/imusage.html